# Dell Dimension audio driver for Windows 7

Tags: drivers, dell-dimension

Recently I installed Windows 7 on my old Dell Dimension 4600 PC. I got video drivers but still cannot find an audio driver.

Can anyone advise me where I can find a suitable driver?

Answer (score 0):

[This machine is not officially supported under Windows 7.](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/document?journalid=95C574B695E74E55E040AC0A63E97EE5&docid=364766)  [The manufacturer does not offer Windows 7 drivers.](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&ServiceTag=&SystemID=DIM_P4_4600&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=&impid=)

You might try finding a machine with the same audio chipset and seeing if you can find a driver, but you may be out of luck...this chipset is old enough that there may plain just not be a driver for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this driver package

ftp://ftp.us.dell.com/audio/R145551.EXE

.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to the Dell support site, enter your service tag and go to the configurations tab to see the exact items that came in the machine.  Look to see if it lists the audio chipset.  That and/or go to the drivers section, lookup drivers as if your OS was XP.  Look at what kind of chipset the driver support.  Then search for the manufacturer's website and see if they supply updated drivers.